# how to get last 30 days record in codeigniter

Tags: php

my model.

```
public function get_data() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('one_month_report');
            $this->db->where('store_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: <?php
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()');
    $this->db->where($conditions);
    $result = $this->db->get($table); 
?> Yes this is duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public function get_data() 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('one_month_report');
    $this->db->where('store_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
            return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()